# Make option as unclickable in multi dropdown using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

If I add some options and save it, after reloading the page it should be shown in dropdown and it should be unclickable. I use the `("#OpsLead_taglist").prop("disabled", true)`, value is not showing in the dropdown list. Otherwise it is not making readonly. As per criteria it should be readonly and can add new lists in that dropdown. Kindly suggest me. I can't handle this.
[image]

Source Code:

```
var opsmultiselect = $("#OpsLead").data("kendoMultiSelect");
$(this).attr("disabled", true);//not working
```

Comment: Try `$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: why put something in a dropdown list if the user can't select it?

Comment: disabled means not fully not showing. i want to show the value but it is not removable. we can add new items. but could not delete the existing one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent some items from being deselected
you could do this by decorating them with a css-class and let the eventlistener decide whether to prevent the deselection or not.

```
function onDeselect(e){ 
  if($(e.item).hasClass("k-state-disabled")) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
//To make it readonly
$("#OpsLead").data("kendoMultiSelect").readonly(true);

//To make it editable again
$("#OpsLead").data("kendoMultiSelect").readonly(false);
```